# Magento 2.1 Theme option not available in Store > Configuration > General > Design

Tags: theme, magento-2.1

I installed Magento 2.1 successfully.But When I go Store > Configuration > Design,theme option not avaiable.I tried pub deploy and flush cache and reindex command but theme option not available in Magento 2.1.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to go for naviagation menu **Content**

```
Content -> Design -> Theme
```

Menu.
Here you can get all theme and all configuration are get from here.

Comment: plz let me know if any issue are available

Comment: Thanks for answer but in magento2.1 only one user can login in admin it means that if another user try to login same time,if another user logged in admin so it will automatically logout.this issue in magento2.1,any suggestion ?

Comment: sorry this issue is not known for me

Comment: I am accepting answer but throw message is 'wait 3 min' after 3 min i accept answer

Comment: ok sure no problem

Answer (score 3):

**Change Magento theme in 2.1 Version**
[image: If you want to Chagne Theme in Magento 2.1 Version Go to Admin Content Section than click here you see Magento Default theme.]

Answer (score 0):

In Order to change theme for particular website/store go to 
Content>>Design>>Configuration

[image]

Here you can set different theme for different stores as per your requirement.