# Theme configuration in Magento 2.1 Bug?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have installed magento2.1 in local pc. After I created one custom theme then, I Go to change my custom theme via admin **Store -> Configuration -> General -> Design**  But Here Theme Selection option is not there , Is magento 2.1 Bug?

Reference:

[image]

Comment: you can find more hint from here, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124236/magento-2-1-theme-option-not-available-in-store-configuration-general-desi/124239#124239

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your installation. I believe they moved it to the design tab in a newer version.

In my 2.1 version also it shows same. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aJL9nhfbfFZ3JKeWszcVczSjQ/view?usp=drivesdk

It seems the theme configuration was moved.

It can be found in main administration menu:

Content -> Design -> Configuration Click on scope you are interested in(probably the first one) and change 'Applied theme'.

Answer (score 3):

In magento 2.1 they change the menu for theme configuration. you can navigate to theme configuration  by

**Content -> Design -> configuration**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No That is no bug

replace 2.1 in

Please go to content-> Configuration -> edit